# Bitcoin core - get transaction information in PHP

Tags: bitcoin-core, php

I've using Bitcoin core and I've downloaded **denpamusic/php-bitcoinrpc** with composer.

I can get block information with this:

```
$block = $bitcoind->getBlock('000000000019d6689c085ae165831e934ff763ae46a2a6c172b3f1b60a8ce26f');
print_r($block);
```

But I can't get information directly with transaction ID.

Is it possible to get all information from transaction **only with TXID**?

Or there is possible terminal method with bitcoin-cli

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/issues/22524#issuecomment-884663685

Comment: You can share the steps that helped you resolve this question by answering your own question below. Can be helpful for others who search related things in future.